# VSCode Extension write and open file

Tags: visual-studio-code, file-io, vscode-extensions

My requirement is actually pretty simple, I want to write a file and open it in vscode. But I can't get this to work:

```
var content = rec[rt.fields[field]];
var filePath = path.join(vscode.workspace.rootPath, selected.label + '.' + field);
fs.writeFileSync(filePath, content, 'utf8');

var openPath = vscode.Uri.parse(filePath);
vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(openPath).then(doc => {
  vscode.window.showTextDocument(doc);
});
```

I get the following error message and have no idea what that should mean:

> cannot open c:%5CUsers%5Cmak%5C.sneditor%5Csoftpointdev1.service-now.com%5CRMCostPlanHelper.js. Detail: No model with uri 'c:%5CUsers%5Cmak%5C.sneditor%5Csoftpointdev1.service-now.com%5CRMCostPlanHelper.js' nor a resolver for the scheme 'c'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I also encountered a similar problem. You can also solve your problem by doing the following:

```js
var content = rec[rt.fields[field]];
var filePath = path.join(vscode.workspace.rootPath, selected.label + '.' + field);
fs.writeFileSync(filePath, content, 'utf8');

var openPath = vscode.Uri.parse("file:///" + filePath); //A request file path
vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(openPath).then(doc => {
  vscode.window.showTextDocument(doc);
});
```

Comment: `rootPath` is deprecated. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Use the `workspaceFolders` property. `rootPath` used to give only the first entry, so you can do `workspaceFolders[0].uri`. More details in the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#workspace)

Answer (score 17):

As soon as a posted this Question I found out the answer ^^

You have to use `vscode.Uri.file` not `vscode.Uri.parse`

```js
const content = 'exampleContent';
const filePath = path.join(vscode.workspace.rootPath, 'fileName.extension');
fs.writeFileSync(filePath, content, 'utf8');

const openPath = vscode.Uri.file(filePath);
vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(openPath).then(doc => {
    vscode.window.showTextDocument(doc);
});
```

Comment: working! but `rootPath` is deprecated. How can I fix that?